# Am I calling free() correclty on my struct pointer?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

So while testing my struct I use the following method. You can see that I call free on the pointer at the end of the method. Is this right?

```
void test() {

    VariableVector *labelVector = initVariableVector();
    VariableVector *variableVector = initVariableVector();

    // do some stuff with labelVector and variableVector

    free(labelVector);
    free(variableVector);
}
```

This is what my struct init methods look like:

```
Variable* initVariable(char *variableName, char *arrayOfElements,
        int32_t address) {
    Variable* initializedVariable = malloc(sizeof(Variable));
    if (initializedVariable != NULL ) {
        initializedVariable->variableName = variableName;
        initializedVariable->arrayOfElements = arrayOfElements;
        initializedVariable->address = address;
        return initializedVariable;
    } else {
        return NULL ;
    }
}

VariableVector* initVariableVector() {
    VariableVector* initializedVariableVector = malloc(
            sizeof(VariableVector));
    if (initializedVariableVector != NULL ) {
        initializedVariableVector->size = 0;
        initializedVariableVector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        initializedVariableVector->variables = malloc(
                sizeof(Variable) * VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        return initializedVariableVector;
    } else {
        return NULL ;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO's purpose is not to do code review, so your question is really borderline. What is it in particular that you don't understand in such a basic example for `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: Well, one thing you should do is first "free" all the pointers you've malloc-ed when initializing your variableVector pointer (like initializedVariableVector->variables), and then free variableVector

Comment: When coding in C, functions that take no arguments should have argument type `void`. You should have `VariableVector* initVariableVector(void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but your implementation is not.

`initVariableVector()` does 2 `malloc`'s for one object, but you only do 1 `free`.

You should have function to destroy it too.

```
void destroyVariableVector(VariableVector* vector)
{
    if(vector) {
        free(vector->variables);
        free(vector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You're not checking whether the memory allocation for the member "variables" in structure VariableVector is successful. Which means that even at the end you do not free it manually, so it leads to memory leak.

My advice:
Use "init*" functions, but at the same time use "free*" functions. It keeps the code clearer and takes care of all memory releasing.

initVariableVector, the opposite should be freeVariableVector

And the latter function could look like:

```
void freeVariableVector(VariableVector *vv)
{
    if (vv) {
        if (vv->variables)
            free(vv->variables);
        free(vv);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 the code is not correct because the `->variables` member on each `VariableVector` needs to be freed before freeing the `VariableVector`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I must have overlooked it. I thought he was just filling the structure members with static data, sorry.

But after all, the advice that he should use "init*" and "free*" functions was correct, to my mind. It keeps the code clear.