# How do I free my custom struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

So I wrote my 2 structs in a file:

```
struct _Variable {
    char *variableName;
    char *arrayOfElements;
    int32_t address;
};
typedef struct _Variable Variable;

struct _VariableVector {
    int size; // elements full in array
    int capacity; // total available elements
    Variable *variables;
};
typedef struct _VariableVector VariableVector;
```

and I also implemented a init method for each:

```
Variable* initVariable(char *variableName, char *arrayOfElements,
        int32_t address) {
    Variable* initializedVariable = malloc(sizeof(Variable));
    if (initializedVariable != NULL ) {
        initializedVariable->variableName = variableName;
        initializedVariable->arrayOfElements = arrayOfElements;
        initializedVariable->address = address;
        return initializedVariable;
    } else {
        return NULL ;
    }
}

VariableVector* initVariableVector() {
    VariableVector* initializedVariableVector = malloc(
            sizeof(VariableVector));
    if (initializedVariableVector != NULL ) {
        initializedVariableVector->size = 0;
        initializedVariableVector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        initializedVariableVector->variables = malloc(
                sizeof(Variable) * VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
        return initializedVariableVector;
    } else {
        return NULL ;
    }
}
```

now I would like to write a `freeVariable(Variable* variable)` method and a `freeVariableVector(VariableVector* variableVector)` method. But I don't know how?

Comment: What's the difference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143630/am-i-calling-free-correclty-on-my-struct-pointer?rq=1 ?

Comment: Now that i know I was doing it wrong I have no idea how to write the free functions

Comment: For your own sake, I recommend writing shorter names! `initializedVariableVector` is very hard to read and the meaning of `var_vec` as a local variable in a 5 line functions is equally clear, but is much easier to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `free` on the pointer you want to free. As answered in your other [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143630/am-i-calling-free-correclty-on-my-struct-pointer?rq=1).